# What is the correct way to deal with medium-sized byte arrays in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

Many languages and frameworks offer a "byte array" type, but the C++ standard library does not. What type is appropriate to use for medium-sized<sup>1</sup>, resizable byte arrays and how can I use that type efficiently? (particularly: allocating, passing as parameters and destroying)

---

<sup>1: By medium-sized I mean less than a 100 MB.</sup>

Comment: What do you need that (for example) a `std::vector<uint8_t>` doesn't offer?

Comment: `std::array` or `vector`

Comment: Can I pass around that without copying the whole contents?

Comment: void f(const std::vector<uint8_t> &vec);

Comment: You can pass around references or pointers (or smart pointers) to vectors without copying contents.

Comment: If you use move semantics then you can avoid any extra copying of the vector.

Comment: `unsigned char` is the type for a byte, `uint8_t` is the type for an octet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::vector<unsigned char>`, or as @Oli suggested `std::vector<uint8_t>`. Yes, you can pass around it, without copying the whole contents.

```
void f(std::vector<unsigned char> & byteArray) //pass by reference : no copy!
{
     //
}

std::vector<unsigned char>  byteArray;
//...
f(byteArray); //no copying is being made!
```

Comment: what about returning an array of bytes?

Comment: @Tamás : (N)RVO makes that a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Many languages and frameworks offer a "byte array" type, but the C++ standard library does not.

You're wrong here, C++ has a byte array type: `std::vector<unsigned char>`, whose storage is guaranteed to be continuous (there are other alternatives if you do not need this condition). You may want to read about references, move semantics, return value optimization and copy elision to know how to deal with those effectively.

*Note: a byte, in C++ speak, is a `char` (either signed or unsigned). It may not be 8 bits long, you can get its size in bits via the `CHAR_BITS` macro.*

Comment: Note that `char` is not really a reliable _byte_ since it is either signed or unsigned IIRC.

Comment: @D.Shawley: Yes, you don't know whether it is signed or unsigned. Better to have it unsigned if you want to make sense of the numbers as something modulo 2^n.

Answer (score 0):

`vector<char>` should be fine for your purposes.  If you want a shared version to avoid copying you can use the following:

```
typedef shared_ptr<vector<uint8_t>> ByteArray;
```

if you know the size at compile-time you can use `array` which is slightly more space efficient.

also `string` can handle null characters which may or may not be more appropriate than vector.

Some extended implementations have a rope implementation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope, http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html-3.4.6/rope.html, that may be more appropriate.

Comment: Is it even legal for an implementation to share `std::vector<>` contents?  I know there are special permissions for `std::string`, but there are [known problems with COW semantics for strings](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/string_discussion.html).  And how do you know that "most implementations" actually implement this?

Comment: @AndréCaron: I thought I saw it in gcc and msvc.  Hang on I'll check (gcc at least).

Comment: @AndréCaron: `std::string` is COW on gcc 4.7.  Checking vector.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Ok vector copy constructor calls uninitialized_copy_a.  Must have misremembered.  Will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are performance reasons for using unique_ptr instead, at least for relatively large buffers. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35798248/1992615 for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++17 you can use

```
std::vector<std::byte> buffer;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using `std::deque<uint8_t>` instead of `std::vector<uint8_t>` since the latter requires contiguous chunks of memory.  I would steer clear of allocating large blocks of memory with `new` since it will initialize the block of memory using the default constructor which might be a little more expensive than you want.

In a pinch, I believe that you can customize `boost::shared_ptr` with a custom deallocator so that you can allocate with `std::malloc` avoiding the initialization overhead and deallocate with `std::free` while still maintaining the goodness that `shared_ptr` brings to the table.

Comment: "*I would steer clear of allocating large blocks of memory with `new` since it will initialize the block of memory using the default constructor which might be a little more expensive than you want.*" If you're talking about raw C-arrays, whether the data is initialized or not depends on whether one uses default-initialization or value-initialization (i.e. `new unsigned char[num]` vs `new unsigned char[num]()`). The former is _not_ guaranteed to initialize the memory, the latter is. `malloc` is never a good suggestion.

Comment: IIRC, `std::vector` uses the initializing version.  It probably does not matter a lot but there is quite a difference in the performance of the options.  For example, allocating a 100,000,000 `vector` takes 177ms whereas `new`ing it w/initialization takes 253ms, w/o initialization takes 0.051ms and `malloc` takes 0.030ms.  I ran into this when I was using `std::vector` for largish protocol buffers.

Comment: `std::vector<>` doesn't use `new` at all, it uses the allocator you specify as the second template argument. You're right that it will initialize elements if using `resize` or the constructor that takes a size, but this is what `reserve` is for. :-]