# Modern C++ idiom for allocating / deallocating an I/O buffer

Tags: c++, memory-management, io

For I/O work, I need to read N bytes into a buffer.  N is known at run time (not compile time).  The buffer size will never change.  The buffer is passed to other routines to compress, encrypt, etc: it's just a sequence of bytes, nothing higher than that.

In C, I would allocate the buffer with `malloc` and then `free` it when I'm done.  However, my code is modern C++, certainly no `malloc`s in place, and very few raw `new` and `delete`: I'm making heavy use of RAII and `shared_ptr`.  None of those techniques seem appropriate for this buffer, however.  It's just a fixed length buffer of bytes, to receive I/O and make its contents available.

Is there a modern C++ idiom to this elegantly? Or, for this aspect, should I just stick with good ol' `malloc`?

Comment: `std::vector`. Always `std::vector`. well... almost unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: Starting from C++11, you can even access the raw storage behind a vector using `.data()`

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Always could with `&front()` (for non-empty only, granted)

Comment: Aside: have you considered subclassing `streambuf` as your means for providing functionality?

Comment: Like everyone else, I say use `std::vector`.

Comment: Vector isn't necessarily a great idea, it requires initialization of the elements which can be a performance hit unless you can recycle the buffer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In **C++14**, there's a very syntactically clean way of achieving what you want:

```
size_t n = /* size of buffer */;
auto buf_ptr = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(n);
auto nr = ::read(STDIN_FILENO, buf_ptr.get(), n);
auto nw = ::write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf_ptr.get(), nr);
// etc.
// buffer is freed automatically when buf_ptr goes out of scope
```

Note that the above construct will value-initialize (zero out) the buffer. If you want to skip the initialization to save a few cycles, you'll have to use the slightly uglier form given by lisyarus:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> buf_ptr(new uint8_t[n]);
```

**C++20** introduces `std::make_unique_for_overwrite`, which allows the non-initializing line above to be written more concisely as:

```
auto buf_ptr = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<uint8_t[]>(n);
```

Comment: Another huge advantage of Matt's answer is because there is a massive improvement in destruction time. I recently converted some code from using a large vector as a buffer, with destruction time measured in seconds, to a unique_ptr with effectively instant destruction.

Comment: @Nanki That's hard to believe; can you explain what may have caused that?

Comment: This turned out to be due to a known bug in VS2015 during debug and didn't affect release code - and it's already been fixed.

Comment: Doesn't the usage of the scope operator, ::, with nothing in front mean it's accessing some sort of global? If not the case for this, what is ::read and ::write calling?

Comment: @JoeManiaci: Be careful with your terminology. Globals can be defined in namespaces other than the global namespace. The `::` prefix specifically denotes a symbol defined in the global namespace. I used it here to clarify that I am calling `read(…)` and `write(…)` functions defined in the global namespace, as opposed to perhaps some member functions.

Comment: @MattWhitlock : All I see here http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/ is mention of file(global) or local scope. Are you referring to something like the Global symbolic constants that they have an example of below in that same link?

Comment: @JoeManiaci: Global functions aren't quite the same as global variables. I'm using the term "global function" as a synonym for "non-member function" — that is, a function not defined as a member of a type. There appears to be some disagreement as to whether these terms are really synonymous. Google's C++ Style Guide says, "Prefer placing nonmember functions in a namespace; use completely global functions rarely." However, "C++ Plus Data Structures," by Nell B. Dale, says, "Global scope is the scope of an identifier declared outside all functions and classes."

Comment: @MattWhitlock Ah, gotcha completely now. Thanks.

Comment: std::make_unique_default_init has been renamed to [std::make_unique_for_overwrite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique). [Some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050872/what-does-stdmake-unique-for-overwrite-do-isnt-it-redundant-with-stdmake) about the function.

Comment: If C++20 allows the line in the middle code block to be written more "concisely" as the third code block, why is the line in third code block _longer_?

Comment: @davidbak: Haha, you noticed that. I meant lexically concisely. It may be longer, but it's syntactically simpler. Code clarity is not directly correlated with code brevity.

Answer (score 23):

Basically, you have two main C++-way choices:

- `std::vector`
- `std::unique_ptr`

I'd prefer the second, since you don't need all the automatic resizing stuff in `std::vector`, and you don't need a container - you need just a buffer.

`std::unique_ptr` has a specialization for dynamic arrays: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` will call `delete []` in it's destructor, and will provide you with appropriate `operator []`.

If you want the code:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char [size]);
some_io_function(buffer.get(), size); // get() returnes raw pointer
```

Unfortunatelly, it doesn't have a way to retrieve the size of the buffer, so you'll have to store it in a variable. If it confuses you, then `std::vector` will do the work:

```
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
some_io_function(buffer.data(), buffer.size()); // data() returnes raw pointer
```

If you want to pass the buffer around, it depends on how exactly you do it.

Consider the following case: the buffer is filled somewhere, then processed somewhere else, stored for some time, then written somewhere and destroyed. It happens that you never really need two places in the code to own the buffer, and you can simply `std::move` it from place to place. For this use case, `std::unique_ptr` will work perfectly, and will protect you from occasionally copying the buffer (while with `std::vector` you can copy it by mistake, and no error or warning will arise).

If, conversely, you need several places in the code to hold the same buffer (maybe it is filled / used / processed in more then one place simultaneously), you definitely need `std::shared_ptr`. Unfortunately, it does not have array-like specialization, so you'll have to pass appropriate deleter:

```
std::shared_ptr<char> buffer(new char[size], std::default_delete<char[]>());
```

The third option is if you really need to copy the buffer. Then, `std::vector` will be simpler. But, as I've already mentioned, I feel that it is not the best way. Also, you can always copy the buffer hold by `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` manually, which clearly documents your intention:

```
std::uniqure_ptr<char[]> buffer_copy(new char[size]);
std::copy(buffer.get(), buffer.get() + size, buffer_copy.get());
```

Comment: Using `std::unique_ptr` may not be the best alternative for a buffer that is supposed to be reused and passed around to multiple functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg nothing said in the question about multiple functions. Btw, from my experience, IO buffers are usually not used this way.  If it is still needed, then `std::vector` won't work either - you'll have to use `std::shared_ptr`, for example.

Comment: "The buffer is passed to other routines to...". Regarding using a vector, at least it's not designed to be passed around primarily by value.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg missed that part, my apologies. Well, you always can move `std::unique_ptr`, and it will also guard you from trying to copy the full buffer (where `std::vector` will happily copy).

Comment: What about using `std::shared_ptr`, since, as @JoachimPileborg mentioned, I need to pass it around?

Comment: Didn't know `std::unique_ptr` had a specialization for arrays, nice.

Comment: Why not a tiny buffer class that tracks the size, and the unique_ptr, that one can then point to using a shared_ptr?

Comment: The problem with the `std::unique_ptr` solution is that it still uses a raw dynamic array which doesn't know it's size (a source of bugs) and doesn't provide iterators (a source of bugs) and can't be used in a range based for loop. A vector on the other hand has proper built in copying and moving whereas manually copying a raw array is another source of bugs. It is hard to imagine a case where a `std::vector` would not be the superior choice.

Comment: @Galik I completely agree with the problems you described. However, as I've said in the answer, `unique_ptr` saves from unintended copyings. Furthermore, it can release the data - something extremely helpful when dealing with plain C API's, for example. Personally, I'd prefer a class with a `unique_ptr` and `size` inside.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, easy:

```
std::vector<char> myBuffer(N);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think its common to use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this.

The benefits of using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) over an manually allocated `char` buffer are copy semantics (for passing to functions that wish to modify the data for their own purposes or when returning the data to a calling function).

Also a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) knows its own size reducing the number of parameters that need passing to processing functions and eliminating a source of bugs.

You have complete control over how the data is passed to other functions - either by *reference* or *const reference* as appropriate.

If you need to call an older *c-style* function with a plain `char*` and length you can easily do that too:

```
// pass by const reference to preserve data
void print_data(const std::vector<char>& buf)
{
    std::cout.fill('0');
    std::cout << "0x";
    for(auto c: buf)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::hex << int(c);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// pass by reference to modify data
void process_data(std::vector<char>& buf)
{
    for(auto& c: buf)
        c += 1;
}

// pass by copy to modify data for another purpose
void reinterpret_data(std::vector<char> buf)
{
    // original data not changed
    process_data(buf);
    print_data(buf);
}

void legacy_function(const char* buf, std::size_t length)
{
    // stuff
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");

    // 24 character contiguous buffer
    std::vector<char> buf(24);

    while(ifs.read(buf.data(), buf.size()))
    {
        // changes data (pass by reference)
        process_data(buf);

        // modifies data internally (pass by value)
        reinterpret_data(buf);

        // non-modifying function (pass by const ref)
        print_data(buf);

        legacy_function(buf.data(), buf.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that really helps me.  The vector needs to be passed to other functions, so I'd need to allocate it with new and then free it.  Besides, is a vector really designed for this type of I/O? Is the data block guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, `std::vector`s storage is specified to be continuous. And thanks to move semantics it is also efficient to pass the vector around by value, no need for reference semantics (and thus memory management)

Comment: @SRobertJames You don't need to allocate your *vector* dynamically to pass it to other functions. Typically you pass by *reference* or *const reference*. I have updated the answer to demonstrate usage. Also `std::vector` is guaranteed to be a contiguous block.

Comment: @SRobertJames I don't understand why you'd have any issues passing it to other functions - just pass it by reference - if there are lifecycle issues you should mention them.

Comment: "Is the data block guaranteed?" I assume you want a block of memory to do a bulk read into? Pass the size you need as an argument to the constructor shown to pre-allocate the buffer and initialize it to 0. There's another form of the constructor that allows you to also pass a value to initialize to in addition to the size, e.g. `std::vector<char> buf(24, 0xff);`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
std::vector<char> buffer(N)
```

If the size of the buffer never changes, you can use it as an array by doing this:

```
char * bufPtr = &buffer[0];
```

This will work in C++03 as well.  See this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/247764/1219722 for details on why this is safe.